# Using "Biopython" - How could I improve my code

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have the following code:

```
from Bio import AlignIO
import itertools

out=open("test.csv","a")
align = AlignIO.read("HPV16_CG.aln.fas", "fasta")
n=0
def SNP(line):  
    result=[]
    result.append(str(n+1))
    result.append(line[0])
    result.append(align[y].id.rsplit("|")[3])
    result.append(x)
    return result



while n<len(align[0]):
  line = align[:,n]
  y=0
  for x in line:
    if line[0]!=x:
      print >> out, ','.join(map(str,SNP(line)))
      y=y+1
    else:
      y=y+1
  y=0
  n=n+1
out.close()

f=open("test.csv","rU")

out=open("test_2.csv","a")
lines=f.read().split()

for key, group in itertools.groupby(lines, lambda line: line.partition(',')[0]):
    print >>out, ','.join(group)

out.close()
f.close()
```

As you can see, I am currently writing two files. I really only need the second file.
Does anyone have any suggestions to combine both "subscripts" into one?

The input file "HPV16_CG.aln.fas" looks like this:

```
>gi|333031|lcl|HPV16REF.1| Alpha-9 - Human Papillomavirus 16, complete genome. 
ACTACAATAATTCATGTATAAAACTAAGGGCGTAACCGAAATCGGTTGAACCGAAACCGG

>gi|333031|gb|K02718.1|PPH16 Human papillomavirus type 16 (HPV16), complete genome
ACTACAATAATTCATGTATAAAACTAAGGGCGTAACCGAAATCGGTTGAACCGAAACCGG

>gi|196170262|gb|FJ006723.1| Human papillomavirus type 16, complete genome
ACTACAATAATTCATGTATAAAACTAAGGGCGTAACCGAAATCGGTTGAACCGAAACCGG
```

I really appreciate all the help/suggestions to help me improve this!

Comment: You need to fix your indentation before we can help you, I'm afraid. See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Comment: If you want general code review, please consider using http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to keep the lines of the file(s) in memory but I suspect that won't work as any useful bioinformatics files are likely quite large.

Here's an attempt at cleaning up the script by removing global variable usage and adding a generator function to create the lines returning from your `SNP` function in a streaming fashion that should be compatible with your `itertools.groupby` call.

```
from Bio import AlignIO
import itertools

n=0
align = AlignIO.read("HPV16_CG.aln.fas", "fasta")

def SNP(line, y, x):
    """Pass y as a parameter rather than relying on a global"""  
    result=[]
    result.append(str(n+1))
    result.append(line[0])
    result.append(align[y].id.rsplit("|")[3])
    result.append(x)
    return result

def generate_snp_lines(align, n):
    """this is a function generator that'll produce lines without writing them to a file"""
    while n<len(align[0]):
        line = align[:,n]
        y=0
        for x in line:
            if line[0]!=x:
                yield ','.join(map(str,SNP(line, y, x)))
            y+=1
        n+=1

def main():

    # let's use a context manager to open and cleanup this file for us:
    with open("test.csv","a") as out:
        # construct the generator:
        lines = generate_snp_lines(align, n)
        # pass it to itertools.groupby like we'd pass any iterable:
        for key, group in itertools.groupby(lines, lambda line: line.partition(',')[0]):
            print >>out, ','.join(group)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for the help. The code produced an empty file...Do you have any idea why that could be?

Comment: I edited the above code...it works but does not quite do what I need

Comment: @Nike It prints everything on a single line, not one line/position as before

Comment: If so add a `\n` at the end of the group after joining it